Robocopy skips folder while deleted
Using below command in Powershell to copy files from one location to the other:
robocopy /s /xo $robo_source $robo_destination
With $robo_source="D:/UploadLogs/Logs" and $robo_destination="D:/Logs" in this specific example.
When deleting the $robo_source folder; i.e. delete the Logs folder (and its subdirectories) in UploadLogs RoboCopy is telling me 2 files are copied and 22 are skipped:

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :        11         0        11         0         0         0
   Files :        24         2        22         0         0         0
   Bytes :   11.13 m   816.1 k   10.34 m         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
   Ended : Wednesday, December 18, 2024 9:12:15 AM

I don't see the files that are copied however and also it is not clear to me why 22 files are skipped as I dont have any file anymore.
Is there a way to prevent this for happening?
The option /XO is to avoid copying files which are already there. Is there caching in place which I can clear?

Use absolute paths instead of relative (to PowerShell) paths when running robocopy

Why is that better in your opinion?

Because what is relative to PowerShell (the script) is not the same as what is relative to robocopy.exe. When calling an application outside Powershell always use full absolute paths

Have adjusted that in the code. However, still the same behavior occurs.

The naming is a bit confusing because in the robocopy command source folder is first and destination is 2nd but you have named your 2nd variable $source.  Is your intention to copy from /Logs to ./UploadLogs/Logs or the other way around?  Also is there a reason for using dynamic ${dir} variable name for the other rather than something like $destination="/Logs"?  May not matter, but nice to have these details to try and help

Yes correct, I want to copy from /Logs to ./UploadLogs/Logs (the naming was confusing indeed and I have adjusted that)

Your question still shows that you are copying from D:/UploadLogs/Logs to D:/Logs - Additionally, your use of forward slashes instead of back slashes could be causing some of your issues. Check the initial summary when running robocopy and verify the parameters it's being run with are actually what you want
